# bash script while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

hi i am new in bash scripting.
This is my script in this i use while loop this is working till giving input to ping the ips in serverfile but further i want to use those ips to make files of each ip as below i am doing  but it has some issue i think there must be more while loops in it . but its not working it takes only one ip as input and make the only one file and further adding in the required file its not working on whole input lets say there are 5 ips in the file it only make the first ip file.

```
#!/bin/bash

l2=$(tail -1 /root/serverfile | grep hadoop | tr ' ' '\n' | grep hadoop)

awk '{print $1}' < serverFile.txt | while read ip; do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
          cd /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/Hadoop 
          cp Hadoop-node.cfg   $l2.cfg 
          sed -i 's/192.168.0.1/'$ip'/' $l2.cfg 
          sed -i 's/Hadoop-node/'$l2'/' $l2.cfg 
          echo "cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/Hadoop/$l2.cfg" >> /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg 

         service nagios restart
          echo " Node is added successfull"
          echo $ip IS UP
    else
        echo $ip IS DOWN NOT PINGING
    fi
done
```

Comment: Whats the question ?

Comment: but its not working it takes only one ip as input and make the only one file and further adding in the required file its not working on whole input lets say there are 5 ips in the file it only make the first ip file.

Comment: A good reproducer -- to let other people observe and help with your problem -- is something that other people can run themselves, without needing other software like Nagios installed, or files in specific places (`/root/serverfile`, etc), or systems with specific IPs on their networks. See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve